# How can I add .htpasswd with Laravel Forge for Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-nova, .htpasswd

I´m using **Laravel 10 with Laravel Nova 4.31**. For deployment / server management I use Laravel Forge.

Now I want to **protect the route /nova with .htaccess/.htpasswd** (= "Security Rules" in Forge). When I add a new rule **for path "/nova"** the route is protected by properly - I have to enter my credentials on page load and the login screen is loaded.

However, as Nova uses Inertia many **requests are sent as XHR which fail** due to the .htpasswd protection. For example: The login screen for nova is loaded as expected but the login doesn´t work (cause the XHR request in the background is blocked).

Is there a **proper way to configure .htaccess/.htpasswd** to protect the /nova route and allow XHR communication for Nova?